# How can I rewrite the output of image field to become a div with this image as a background image?

Tags: views, 8, theming

I have a view to display a content that have an image field, and I need to display this image as a background image of a div so I can apply some CSS on it.

what I tried to do is to rewrite the output of this field using twig to be like this:

```
<div class="page-image" style="background-image: url({{ field_image }});">
</div>
```

the problem is that Drupal strips style attribute so the output will be like this:

```
<div class="page-image">
</div>
```

In D7 I used to fix this kind of issues by overriding the template for the specific field, but I couldn't figure out what is the name of the needed template in D8. when I enabled twig debug it turned out that the field is using the template file `views-view-field.html.twig` which is the default template for all fields in views, but I couldn't find the needed template name for this specific field in this view, I tried to rename it like in D7 to be `views-view-field--page-image--field-image.html.twig` (the view name is page_image) but it didn't work out.

any suggestions?

Comment: Note that rendering images through CSS background only makes sense when the image is for decorative purpose. If the image itself has a value for site visitors it's better to render it through `<img/>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Set all fields to "Exclude from display", add a "Global: Custom text" field and then build your html there using the "Replacement patterns" available.

I assume this still works in drupal 8.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, I already did that, but the problem is that Drupal strips _style_ attribute from the _div_ tag! and my replacement pattern field is in this attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't done that in Views just yet, I did have to put a image as background-image in the Page Title template.
The same technique might work in this case as well.

In the preprocess, I did this :

```
$variables['header_attributes'] = new Attribute(array(
  'style' => "background-image: url('" . $headerImage->toString() . "');",
));
```

And then, in `page-title.html.twig`, I just did this ( headerClass is just another class I add in the Twig template itself :

```
<header {{ header_attributes.addClass(headerClass) }}>
```

And this works fine. My style attribute doesn't get stripped off.

Don't forget to add `use Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute;` at the top, if you want to give this a try.